# closeTab function not working IE8 - Service Cloud Console integration toolkit

Tags: service-cloud-console

closeTab function is not working in IE8, however the same works in Chrome with no issue.

```
sforce.console.getPrimaryTabIds(function (result){

                    sforce.console.getEnclosingTabId(function (success){                
                            sforce.console.closeTab(success.id);                                    
                        });

                    sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null, caseurl , true,'',function(openSuccess){});             
                });
```

Please help, advice. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have any errors on the page? Is there a yellow triangle with exclamation mark in the bottom left corner of IE status bar?

Comment: @Bachovski - Nope, I dont have any error in the bottom left coerner. Any further advice?